# Fetch shared storage usage info from Windows server

Tags: windows, scripting, wmic

I am trying to retrieve usage related info of shared storage attached to a server by using:

`WMIC logicaldisk get size,freespace,caption,drivetype /Format:csv`

The output is fine. But here the Drive type for drive-D is showing as 3, though its a Netapp Lun. Please let me know how to get Lun information. Its becomes tough for me to identify a Netapp volume if it is showing Netapp as Drivetype 3.
I do not have powershell installed in all the servers so I can't use PS.

Output:

```
Node, Caption, DriveType, FreeSpace, Size
Hostname, C:, 3, 1522081792, 20973137920
Hostname, D:, 3, 38534803456, 751148986368
Hostname, E:, 3, 2867924992, 52395274240
Hostname, F:, 3, 44005818368, 73364254720
Hostname, R:, 5, ,
```

Comment: Kindly edit your Question....

Comment: Could  _Netapp LUN_ be found in a `wmi` class property? E.g. [`Win32_DiskDrive` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132(v=vs.85).aspx)? I guess `SCSIBus`, `SCSILogicalUnit`, `SCSIPort`, `SCSITargetId` for instance.